# Voltage drop across power supply rail

Tags: power-supply, linear-regulator

I have multiple PCBs which are communicating via CAN and are supplied by two power sources (5V and 24V). After the first field test we noticed a considerable voltage drop at the power supply between the slaves (0.4V for ~30m). Of course this is a common effect.

What is the best way to 'counter' this behavior when some parts of the PCB need an accurate 5/24V.

My thought: Increase the supply to 5.5-6V (max distance ~50m) and create the reference voltage on each PCB individual using a 'linear voltage regulator'. Since the delta between the 'supply' and the 'reference' is relatively short I would also not burn too much power while regulating.

Is there a better way too accomplish a stable 5V (\$\pm 1\%\$) supply for my PCBs?

Comment: The voltage drop issue when suppling voltage over great distances has been around for decades and the world is stepping up the voltage at the beginning of the line, and stepping it back down at the end - just like you are suggesting. So I would not necesarily ask for a "better" way, but rather other ways out of curiosity ; since electricity supply techniques are mostly cost-driven, perhaps there exists another elegant technique though, and in that case I too will be glad to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

The CAN buss ICs are designed to tolerate much more than 1% vdd drops.

You need to reduce the I*R drops by 5:1 or 8:1.

Each square of PCB foil is 0.000500 (1/2,000th) ohm. You should account for that I*R voltage drop in your multi-PCB system. A trace between Input connector and Output connector, of size 2" by 0.05", has 40 squares of resistance, thus 20 milliOhms.

At 1 amp, the I*R drop is 20 milliVolts.